# Add some data to table on first run in asp.net core(Fill database)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i'm creating a web site using Asp.net core and i want to add some records to some tables at first time i run my website (on host i mean) for example category names or any .

Does any know how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the described approaches from  [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding) article.

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        DataSeeder.SeedCountries(context);
    }
    host.Run();
}
```